# Connecting to mosquitto broker using paho client app on android - works in virtual device in android studio, but not on actual physical device,

Tags: android, react-native, mqtt

I would like to make android app for IoT communication with some ESP32 dvices using MQTT. I have mosquitto broker running on raspberry pi (but I have it also running under win11, not sure which one will I use in the end). I have everything set in separate network not connected to WAN. I am trying to make mobile app in react-native using typescript with nodejs. I have managed to get running client in some MQTT library that uses Paho client which as I understand was originally designed for browser communication so it is natively websocket only. So I added listener for websockets port 9001 in mosquitto. I am using android studio virtual device on win11 for testing. Everything was working fine, client connected to mosquitto, messages were sent and received.
Then I built the app using "gradlew assembleRelease" and installed it on physical mobile device where I could not connect to mosquitto broker at all. I am able to ping RaspPi with broker from device. When I run app it immediately shows unable to connect, even though there is 3s timeout. When I check netstat -s on raspPi it doesn't show any failed connections.
Here is "netstat -nc | grep tcp":

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          127.0.0.1:54574         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54850         127.0.0.1:5939          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54574         127.0.0.1:5939          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          127.0.0.1:54850         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    188 192.168.0.101:5938      192.168.0.103:50747     ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 192.168.0.101:9001      192.168.0.103:60825     ESTABLISHED
```

192.168.0.103 is win11 with virtual android device running connected to mosquitto broker (192.168.0.101). I was trying to connect from physical device but it didn't show anything, "netstat -s" gives 0 failed tcp connections:

```
Tcp:
10 active connection openings
70 passive connection openings
0 failed connection attempts
1 connection resets received
6 connections established
330663 segments received
343480 segments sent out
154 segments retransmitted
0 bad segments received
10 resets sent
```

Mosquitto -v also didn't notice any connection attempt when I tried to connect from physical device, only showed the client from pc virtual device.
Is it some problem with mobile device, some permissions or something? Is the bulding of app with gradle equivalent to running it using 'npm start' with virtual device?

Here is part of my code:
Apk.tsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect  } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Alert, Settings } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {HomeScreen, DeviceTabs, mqtt} from './components';
import {SafeAreaProvider} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'; // Import AsyncStorage

import {MqttClient} from './utils/MqttClient';

const backgroundImage = require('./assets/login_background.png'); // Replace with the path to your image

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('Test');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('Test');
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  const authenticate = () => {
    if (username === 'Test' && password === 'Test') {
      setAuthenticated(true);
    } else {
      Alert.alert('Invalid credentials. Please try again.');
    }
  };

  if (!authenticated) {
    return (
      <ImageBackground source={backgroundImage} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Username"
            value={username}
            onChangeText={(text) => setUsername(text)}
            style={styles.input}
          />
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Password"
            secureTextEntry
            value={password}
            onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
            style={styles.input}
          />
          <Button title="Login" onPress={authenticate} />
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }

 
  let client = new MqttClient(mqtt.brokerAddress, mqtt.webSocketPort, mqtt.options.clientId); 
  exports.client = client;

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="HomeScreen"
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{title: 'Homescreen'}}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Devices"
            component={DeviceTabs}
            options={{title: 'Devices'}}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
}
```

Homescreen.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';



export function HomeScreen() {
  const [mqttConnected, setMqttConnected] = React.useState('');

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const app=require("../App");
  const client = app.client;

 React.useEffect(() => {
    client.onConnect(onSuccess, onConnectionLost);
  }, []);


  const onSuccess = () => {
    console.info('Mqtt Connected');
    setMqttConnected(true);
  };

  const onConnectionLost = () => {
    setMqttConnected(false);
    console.info('Mqtt Disconnected');
  };



  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.statusContainer}>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: '#fff',
            fontWeight: '600',
          }}>
          {mqttConnected ? 'MQTT connected' : 'Not connected'}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <Text
          style={{
            color: '#888',
            fontWeight: '600',
            fontSize: 30,
            paddingHorizontal: 10, 
          }}>
          Welcome
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Devices")} title="Devices"></Button>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

MqttClient.js:

```
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import initialize from '../lib';

initialize();
export class MqttClient {
  constructor(address, port, id) {
    this.brokerAddress = address;
    this.webSocketPort = port;
    clientId = id;
    this.client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(this.brokerAddress, this.webSocketPort, clientId);
    //this.client = new Paho.MQTT.Client('192.168.0.101', 9001, clientId);
    this.client.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived;
    this.callbacks = {};
    this.onSuccessHandler = undefined;
    this.onConnectionLostHandler = undefined;
    this.isConnected = false;
  }

  isClientConnected() {
    return this.isConnected;
  }

  onConnect = (onSuccessHandler, onConnectionLostHandler) => {
    this.onSuccessHandler = onSuccessHandler;
    this.onConnectionLostHandler = onConnectionLostHandler;

    this.client.onConnectionLost = () => {
      this.isConnected = false;
      onConnectionLostHandler();
    };
    
    this.client.connect({
      timeout: 10,
      onSuccess: () => {
        this.isConnected = true;
        onSuccessHandler();
      },
      useSSL: false,
      onFailure: this.onError,
      reconnect: true,
      keepAliveInterval: 20,
      cleanSession: true,
    });
  };

  onError = ({errorMessage}) => {
    console.log(errorMessage);
    this.isConnected = false;
    Alert.alert('Failed', 'Failed to connect to MQTT', [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
        style: 'cancel',
      },
      {
        text: 'Try Again',
        onPress: () =>
          this.onConnect(
            this.onSuccessHandler,
            this.onConnectionLostHandler,
          ),
      },
    ]);
  };

  onMessageArrived = message => {
    const {payloadString, topic} = message;
    console.log('onMessageArrived:', payloadString);
    this.callbacks[topic](payloadString);
  };

  onPublish = (topic, message) => {
    this.client.publish(topic, message);
  };

  onSubscribe = (topic, callback) => {
    this.callbacks[topic] = callback;
    this.client.subscribe(topic);
  };

  unsubscribe = topic => {
    delete this.callbacks[topic];
    this.client.unsubscribe(topic);
  };
}
```

-------- EDIT -------------

Logcat shows info message every time I try to connect from mobile device:

`AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined.`

I downloaded and run some example code from mqtt.js project, modification for react native RNMQTTDemo. It also ran fine on virtual device, but after compiling and installing on physical phone gives same error:

```
{ invocationContext: undefined,
errorCode: 7,
errorMessage: 'AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined.' }
```

Comment: Not specifically a fix but try to use EMQX Cloud, i was running everything locally and when testing on physical devices it worked but was unpredictable. EMQX Cloud is also reachable from everywhere instead of your home network.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like the system to be independent of internet connection

Answer (score 0):

So it is permissions issue, as one would expect. In virtual device the debug.apk is used that has different androidmanifest.xml than release.apk. Debug .xml contains in <application> section line:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

for permission of accessing non secured domains.
So I added this config also to  manifest for release. Now I can connect to mqtt broker.